# PHP regexp to create new image

Tags: php, regex, image, base64

Hello I have a string which contains post text and base64 png emoticons wrapped between `[img]` and `[/img]`. for example:

```
text wfor the post [img]smile1 base64[/img] some cointinous text [img]smile 2 base64[/img] some other text.
```

How to regexp this to get

```
text wfor the post <img src="base64"> some cointinous text <img src="base64"> some other text.
```

Comment: smile1 and smile 2 are always this type of data 

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAAgAElEQVR4Xuy9d5Ql.........

Comment: I input the data to DB in this format: text [img]data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAA‌​DDPmHLAAAgAElEQVR4Xu‌​y9d5Ql........[/img] some other text [img]data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAA‌​DDPmHLAAAgAElEQVR4Xu‌​y9d5Ql........[/img] and other text.

After I want to output this data and show text with images.

Comment: Either answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will never have `[img]` inside of other `[img]`s. You could use something like:

```
\[img\]([\w\h]+)\h+(base64)\[\/img\]
```

and replace it with:

```
<img src="$2">
```

https://regex101.com/r/JHd88i/1/

`$1` will contain `smile other stuff`.

or per your description in the comments:

```
\[img\](.+?)\[\/img\]
```

then replace with:

```
<img src="$1">
```

https://regex101.com/r/JHd88i/3/

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/810430

PHP Usage:

```
preg_replace('/\[img\](.+?)\[\/img\]/', 
             '<img src="$1">', 
             'text wfor the post [img]smile1 base64[/img] some cointinous text [img]smile 2 base64[/img] some other text.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a preg_replace_callback function where you can refer to a variable of the matched text, and use that in the replacement.

Regular expression: `/\[img\]smile[\s\S]*?\[\/img\]/i`

Beware to escape the special characters with a `\`. Using the i (case insensitive).

https://regex101.com/ is a great resource for testing the regexes.